# Using + in a java enum type

Tags: java, enums

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to use the + character as part of an enum type, but the compiler is complaining about the syntax because I believe it sees it as an operator.

I'd like to do the following:

```
enum mediaType{

   FACEBOOK,GOOGLE+,TWITTER;

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will treat `+` as an operator. You can however choose a different name there:

```
enum mediaType{
    FACEBOOK,
    GOOGLE_PLUS,
    TWITTER;    
}
```

And if you want to use the value `GOOGLE+` only, then have a field of type `String`, storing the value, and also a parameterized constructor.

P.S: As per proper naming convention, the enum name should be `MediaType`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use arithmetic symbols in identifiers.  You need to find something you can use like `GOOGLE_PLUS`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reading the official Java tutorial's section on Naming Conventions will help you:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

You could at least define a `private String myName = "Google+";`  inside the enum, and define a method that a UI can use to get the value you want rather than just displaying the enum's variable itself.

```
public String myName() {
    return myName;
}
```

Comment: name is final method on all Java enum objects.  Using name() as the accessor to get anything other then the enum value name is impossible.

Comment: @BrentWorden - oops, no wonder that sounded familiar.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Many people believe that you are limited to ASCII in Java just like C and C++.

Actually you have the full Unicode character set.

This is perfectly good Java:

```
enum Plus {
  Google,
  GooglePlus,
  Googleᚋ,
  Googleᐩ;
};
```

Not quite a + (which you cannot have in an `enum` because it will be confused with the `+` operator) but it will still carry the impression of a plus.

It seems you can use the `Ogham` character called `muin` which [looks](http://unicode-table.com/en/168B/) a bit like a plus character. Alternatively it seems the *Canadian syllabics final plus* is also acceptable alhough a number of the other [possibilities](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=plus) seem not to be acceptable.